# CSS for PHP Pagination Function

Tags: css, border

I want to ask about my CSS. I have PHP pagination for paging. I want to make a box when the number is selected/active, but what happened is the selected number is not bordered, but the (< a >) text is bordered. My CSS right now is:

```
.paging{
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}

.paging a:visited{
    color:#FFF;
}

.paging a{
    border-color:#FFF;
    border-spacing:20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Anybody knows how to make the selected/active number is bordered and another number is not? Simple explanation: I want to make it opposite (the "a" tag is not bordered, else is bordered). For the logic: "if its not "a" tag it will be bordered"

I've try to create just .paging{border.....}  but what happened is it bordered all the div, not only the number.

Sorry for my mess explanation. Hope You understand it. And please don't ask me to edit the pagination function because I got it from internet and can't read it nicely. That's why I'm using div tag for the number (pagination function result).

===edit

here's the result:
[image: real result now]

and what I want is:
[image: result what i wanted]

Comment: What's the output HTML from the PHP?

Comment: I've inserted image at my post... Thanks for reply

Comment: Can you post the HTML that generates the pagination as well please?

Comment: You can see it at here: http://codepad.org/IvsGn5Cv. for my div tag is like this: echo '<div class="paging">'; $query->printNav(); echo'</div>';

Comment: No, I need to see the HTML that the PHP generates. Do you have a demo site that this is hosted on?

Comment: your are giving the border to .paging a which are obviously the links you can click to change page. If I were you I would inspect with chrome the number you want to give the border, check the tag it has... which won't be an <a> and then give the css property to them. maybe a .paging label or .paging span

Comment: @PeteSimmons unfortunately it haven't hosted yet. But if I inspect element, I got this: http://i58.tinypic.com/5pikra.jpg

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez as I said at my post, I don't know how to read pagination function code, so I don't know where to put that "span" maybe You can help with it? I've put the function above

Comment: umm, I hate no tagged texts. and sorry. no idea php (yet) I work just with asp.net wich use to tag those dinamic elements into spans... spmetimes labels

Comment: and no idea how can you "snipe" that untaged element. I could be done probably with jquery but I don't think it's possible with css. I hope I'm wrong thoug

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling the right function? The PHP class you added here, wraps all the text in <spans> but your screenshot does not have any

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez it's ok mates... I know its like impossible without any tag (which I'm still find it right now at the PHP function)

Comment: @PeteSimmons Yes, it's right function. At php function there's no span too. If it has span tag it would be easier, but unfortunately there's not. Right now I'm just finding the text for showing up the number to give div tag there... But I can't find it...

Comment: @PeteSimmons finally find it... thanks mate for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately find the answer. After searching it for several hours, maybe someone use this pagination function too and want to edit it like what I'm doing, here's the answer.

At the function code, search this:

```
return $strIntBefore . $strNumBefore . $this->_retSpanTag($this->_navOffset + 1) . $strNumAfter . $strIntAfter;
```

And change it to this:

```
return $strIntBefore . $strNumBefore . "<span>" . $this->_retSpanTag($this->_navOffset + 1) . "</span>" . $strNumAfter . $strIntAfter;
```

so at the css files:

```
.paging span{
    border-color:#FFF;
    border-spacing:20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Thank you for Pete Simmons, Alvaro, and Pav who try to help me.

Comment: np mate. glad you could find the way.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting the white border on all boxes is because you have written the border styles in .paging a{}
Here you are telling to apply the white border to all a tags.

Create a new class eg.my-selected-class and call it once user clicks on the pagination. You can add the white border in this class. 
In this way the white border will only be seen when my-selected-class is applied.

Comment: And how would that be achieved through the PHP class that is listed in the OP comments?

Comment: Sorry Pav, I know what happened there, that's why I need solution about how to giving that tags to the function which I don't know how to read that.